# Using flask's render_template for non-displayed HTML pages

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask and in this application I need an HTML file to be generated based upon input and then uploaded to Amazon S3. I know that render_template can be used to dynamically create HTML, but can I save that result to a file instead of displaying it immediately?

Instead of

```
return render_template("index.html")
```

I'm expecting something like

```
file = render_template("index.html")
S3Connection.upload(file)
```

That's mostly pseudocode, but will that work? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `render_template` returns a string. You can do whatever you want with that. The easiest way to upload probably depends on the API - which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't sure on what exactly it returned. That should work for me. If you answer I'll give it the correct answer.